# mongodump 1 single document fails because ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, command-line, mongodump

I'm trying to create a mongo dump for 1 single document inside a mongo collection.

When I do this on windows command line:

```
mongodump /host:x.x.x.x /port:27017 /username:my_user /password:my_pass -d my_db -o C:\fsdump -c "fs.files" -q '{_id: ObjectId("28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec")}'
```

I get this error:

```
positional arguments not allowed: [ObjectId(28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec)}']
```

when I change the id in mongo from `ObjectId("28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec")` to `"28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec"`, and when I dump like this:

```
mongodump /host:x.x.x.x /port:27017 /username:my_user /password:my_pass -d my_db -o C:\fsdump -c "fs.files" -q '{_id: "28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec"}'
```

then it works as expected

**so my question is how can I use mongodump and do filtering on specific ObjectId's ?**

or is there another way to create an export for a subset of documents in a collection (instead of the entire collection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectId("28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec")` is a javascript function call to the ObjectId constructor.  This is not valid JSON.  `"28ad7bkjia3e927d690385ec"` is also not a valid ObjectId.

Mongodump uses an extended form of JSON, which had a tag to indicate the field type, so you would specify an ObjectId like this:

`-q '{"_id":{"$oid":"5f76b7cc0311bd14f80a3dec"}}'`

Comment: I didn't know about $oid, it works, thx! (btw on windows I also had to escape everything using double quotes like this: `-q "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"5cf923a14e401624b099f4ce\"}}"`)